# Memory intersection problem in IAR Embedded Workbench

Tags: c, iar

Good day. I'm new to microcontroller programming. I work with ARM Cortex-M4 core, MK12DN512VLK5. The program contains code in assembler and C in IAR Embedded Workbench. The assembler code defines many service variables and writes them to addresses starting at 0x1fff8000. This number is the start of the RAM memory. In C code there is a static array that begins to be written at the address 0x1fff8000. All this leads to overlap of areas and further errors.

Help divide the areas, it is advisable to tell the compiler to start placing the static array from a certain address, e.g. 0x1fff8000+(maximum memory used by assembler). Thanks in advance.

Example of assembler code:
my_variable   equ   0x1fff8000

Example of C code:
static float my_array[100];

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre], which consists of the assembler part, the C part, the linker script, and the commands to assemble, compile, and link the program. You might want to add the linker map, too. We cannot help you without that. -- Generally, it is an error to allocate variables at fixed addresses in the source code, independent of the programming language.

Comment: Learn how to use scatter files

Comment: What is a scatter file? You mean .icf file?

Comment: I can't remember the exact syntax, but it should go something like this: In icf file first `define block` of size of memory used by assember. Then use `place at address` to place the block in preferred address. Finally add `keep` instruction to make sure block is always included. This should inform the linker that the particular data section is in use already.

Comment: If you want to refer to assember section symbols  from C code, then things might get more complicated, and I can't remember how to do that.

Comment: This is not a [mre]. We need all source code and commands **to reproduce**. -- Your assembler source does not define a variable. It defines an address.

Comment: the busybee, I'm sorry I have to ignore the demands. The fact is that part of the assembler code is not available to me for demonstration. I only have access to the table with definitions of variable addresses that assembler code uses.

Comment: @user694733, thanks for the comment. I tried the code in .icf file and it solves the problem:                                                                                                                 
define block ASSEMBLER_CODE with alignment = 8, size = ASSEMBLER_CODE_SIZE {};
place at address mem:0x1fff8000 { block ASSEMBLER_CODE };
keep { block ASSEMBLER_CODE };

Comment: Glad that helped. I recommend that you post that as an answer to this question, so if someone has the same issue in the future they can easily find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the @user694733's comment, it was possible to solve the problem using additional code in the .icf file:

```
define block ASSEMBLER_CODE with alignment = 8, size = ASSEMBLER_CODE_SIZE {};
place at address mem:0x1fff8000 { block ASSEMBLER_CODE };
keep { block ASSEMBLER_CODE };
```

Now, the assembler code accesses memory with addresses from 0x1fff8000 to 0x1fff8000 + ASSEMBLER_CODE_SIZE. In this case, the compiler understands that it is impossible to write to this region and starts writing only after the ASSEMBLER_CODE block.